# How to do a Google Spreadsheet equivalent to SQL's JOIN and SUM( )?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this table:

```
|    A    |  B  |
|---------|-----|
| grocery | $10 |
| clothes | $40 |
| grocery | $19 |
```

etc.

So I'd like to have a column with an aggregation of the categories like grocery and clothes with the total expenses, what in SQL would be a JOIN with the aggregate function SUM()

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I think you're looking for:

### Formula

```
=QUERY(DATA!B1:C3;"SELECT B, SUM(C) GROUP BY B label B 'Type', SUM(C) 'Sum'")
```

### Explained

Column C is aggregated by column B through a summation. Labels are added. 
In this particular case, the usage of `JOIN` in an SQL statement isn't applicable, since the aggregation is done on one table.

### Screenshots

Data:
[image: data]

Result
[image: result]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Sum Aggregate](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdDJXVjBuTzUya1RneklOUS14aG5qTHc&usp=sharing)**

Comment: I changed the label from 'Type' to 'Thank you very much sir! it worked like a charm! :D'

Answer (score 0):

There is a general *Pivot table* tool included in the Spreadsheet application. You find it under *Data → Pivot table report*.

This tool is typically good for _give me the sum of `B` (price) partitioned per `A` (category)"

This would be a pivot table with `row of A` and `value of B, show sum()` which can be built using the pivot table tool.

Comment: Show me the money Dan....

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using JavaScript LINQ (Language Integrated Query).

```
=linq("Enumerable.from('Orders').take(100).join('People', '$.Region', '$.Region',(l, r)=> {return {...l,...r}})", State!$A$1)
```

It lets you specify JavaScript with complex join conditions.  You can also perform other SQL queries such as Grouping, Projecting, Sorting and Filtering your sheets as if they were database tables.  Look at the links below.

Note that in the LINQ query language I replaced all spaces in column names with underscores to make them valid JS identifiers.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DHtQlQUlo-X_YVfo-Wo-b7315sSk2pxL5ci4Y9lxvZo/edit?usp=sharing

https://script.google.com/d/1R5L2ReHJrBRwyoSoVOFLzEQZiGtxidPfPkAeVownt7SWX6TpacY7gA7j/edit?usp=sharing